# SEO friendly URLS HTACCESS PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

On my website I have created my pages like so:

http://www.website.com/page1.php
http://www.website.com/page2.php
http://www.website.com/page3.php

This is not SEO friendly, I really want to display them like this:

http://www.website.com/page1/
http://www.website.com/page2/
http://www.website.com/page3/

What is the best way to do this without putting each of the files in their own directory and naming them index.php.

Ideas please.

Comment: you have keywords in both versions of the URL there will be no SEO benefit in switching in this situation

Comment: Having all those PHP files in a single folder is a lot of clutter. You should be using a front controller instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use apache `mod_rewrite`. Put this in the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This will catch all request paths of the form `/somepage` or `/somepage/` and redirect them to `/somepage.php` (unless the request path refers to an actual file or directory on the server -- in which case it will just serve that file or directory).

Comment: what if the pages have different names. like whatguide.php ?? how can I apply it to all page names

Comment: @user342391, I updated the rewrite rules to work for any files.